# CSS Left property

Tags: css, registration

When you set something as `left: 50px;` in CSS, is the registration in the top left corner, or the center?

Comment: sry i missread, its the Top Left Corner

Comment: Would you mind making that an answer?

Comment: What is 'registration'? `left: 50px` means that the left edge of object must be 50 pixels to the right relative to parent's left edge. What is considered parent is decided by complex rules of CSS box model, mainly influenced by `position` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one sets the registration point to whatever rule you're using.

If you only supply left or right the default registration point is top-left or top-right respectively.

So, for the various style rules:

Left/Left and Top = Top-left Corner

Right/Right and Top = Top-Right Corner

Left/Left and Bot = Bottom Left Corner

Right/Right and Bot = Bottom Right Corner

Answer (score 0):

If the element has `position:relative` it will be moved 50px to the left from where it *should be rendered*. (y position is maintained)

If the element has `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` it will be positioned 50px to the left margin of the first of its' parents which has `position` set to anything but `static`.(if no such parents exist, it will be rendered 50px left of the beginning of the viewport)

If the element has no `position` attribute or `position:static` then the left,right,top,bottom attributes are ignored.

I believe most modern browsers will not modify the elements' y position unless explicitly stated.